# put static json file into indexedDB

Tags: javascript, json, angular, storage, indexeddb

i am trying to store data from a json file stored server side, i am using angular js and html, i can add json data by entering it in my indexeddb function, however i need to pull the feed using http.get and then put it in the db, here is my code.

```
$scope.save_data = function save_data(event) {

let indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB || window.shimIndexedDB;

let open = indexedDB.open("myDB", 1);

open.onupgradeneeded = function () {

    let db = open.result;
    let store = db.createObjectStore("the_Times", { keyPath: "id", value: "Article1" });
    let store1 = db.createObjectStore("the_Times1", { keyPath: "id1", value: "Article2" });
    let store2 = db.createObjectStore("the_Times2", { keyPath: "id2", value: "Article3" });
    let index = store.createIndex("Article1", ["news.Article1"]);
    let index1 = store1.createIndex("Article2", ["news.Article2"]);
    let index2 = store2.createIndex("Article3", ["news.Article3"]);

    open.onsuccess = function (e) {
        let db = open.result;
        let tx = db.transaction("the_Times", "readwrite");
        let tx1 = db.transaction("the_Times1", "readwrite");
        let tx2 = db.transaction("the_Times2", "readwrite");
        let store = tx.objectStore("the_Times");
        let store1 = tx1.objectStore("the_Times1");
        let store2 = tx2.objectStore("the_Times2");
        let index = store.index("Article1");
        let index1 = store1.index("Article2");
        let index2 = store2.index("Article3");
        console.log('added successfully');

        //this is where i want to pull data from a url containing the json data and put it in the DB
        store.put({"JSON string is here... Should be url json data"});
        store1.put({"JSON string is here"});
        store2.put({"JSON string is here"});

        let transaction = db.transaction(["the_Times"], "readonly");
        let objectStore = transaction.objectStore("the_Times", "the_Times1", "the_Times2");
        let cursor = objectStore.openCursor();

        cursor.onsuccess = function (e) {
            let res = e.target.result;
            if (res) {
                console.log(res.key);
                console.dir(res.value);
                res.continue();
            }
            tx.oncomplete = function () {
                db.open();
            };
        }
    }
}
};
```

Comment: you could have edited it with the answer Jack ;) but thankyou

Comment: I sorted this issue out, just before my indexedDB code i added a http.get function... `$http.get("your-JSON-url").then(function (response) {
            editionData = response.data;
            $scope.editionSections = editionData.Sections;
            $scope.editionSectionsNew = editionData.Custom;
            $scope.articleData = editionData.Articles;
            $scope.articleDataUn = editionData.UnsortedData.Data.News;
        });`

Comment: and then in my retrieval code for indexedDB i added editionData... `cursor.value.editionData.UnsortedData.Data.News.Articles[1].Image`